# Want to create a form filler - is java, jsp, html enough?

Tags: java, web

**Summary -** Want to make a simple website form filler. The website is NOT mine and I cannot edit its source code. Don't know what tools/languages are needed. Would java, jsp, html be enough ?

**Request -** Please reconsider your decision to close or downvote. I only need to know if java is enough or not.

There is a form on a website, say for reserving a visit to only one dentist. You fill your details and the date and time you want to visit. Then, it tells you if an appointment can be made or not, somewhere in the webpage.

This web page is NOT protected by CAPTCHA. I don't want to enter my details all the time to look for a reservation. I want to make code to do it for me.

I want to make code which will -

```
1 - Fill the details into the form and "press" submit.
2 - Then, read the resulting page and find out if a reservation is 
    available or not. If yes, do something like maybe - pop up a GUI 
    message, send e-mail or whatever.
3 - Repeat the above steps every 5 hours or so.
```

What are the languages and tools I would need to do this job ? Would I need more than java, jsp and html (thats all i know now) to make such code ?

Thanks.

Comment: There's almost nothing you can't do in Java, so the technical answer to your questions is Yes. However, depending on your requirements you may be over-thinking this. For example, a simple browser extension can do this pretty easily.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly - I never knew that. Which browser extension can I use that instead of code. I have firefox and chrome.

Comment: I'd recommend Chrome. You'll still need to write the extension but that is pretty simple compared to writing a webapp/cron job to do the same in Java. You also might search the Chrome Web store for apps that do something like this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, If you really just want to fill up some forms to check a reservation, no need to code anything, why not just install a plugin, Selenium, record your actions there and just run it at specified times: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Can you help me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357580/is-it-possible-to-do-this-selenium-firefox-ide
  Thanks.

Comment: I am stuck. Looks like Selenium can only provide 70% of the solution to my problem. Please see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358228/java-and-selenium-for-web-form-filling

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you try [CURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). That will make you solution more simple in my opinion.

You can execute HTTP GET/POST with CURL, which is enough to solve your problem. Give it a try, and if you get block you can ask a more specific question about CURL or HTTP.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

You need a web server and a database on the back end.

Since you feel comfortable with Java, JSP/HTML would probably be an ideal solution.

IMHO...

Comment: Im not sure whether this is meant sarcastiacally or not

Comment: Why do I need a web server or database ? Can i not just run "some code" in eclipse and then store the results in a file or send them to an email address ?