# Java and Selenium for web form filling?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

I wanted to fill a web form automatically. I used Selenium IDE to create a script which ENDS with a command that searches for the specified text in the webpage.

I wanted to take action based on this TEXT. If text = congratulations, then send an e-mail to some address. If not, then click ok button. I don't think the Selenium IDE can do this If-else logic and send mail on its own ([Using if / else in selenium ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275354/using-if-else-in-selenium-ide)).

So, I thought of using Java code to "run" this Selenium HTML script, find out if the desired text was found or not - if yes then send mail; otherwise the Java code will "click" the ok button.

Does this approach make sense? Is it possible to do this using Java and some kind of Selenium Java API?

Comment: The reason for doing this little project is in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329996/want-to-create-a-form-filler-is-java-jsp-html-enough

Comment: You can certainly do this in native Java along with the Selenium library, but it isn't possible (or at least, *shouldn't be done*) using the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this reliably in Selenium IDE. The real way to do this is to use Java + Selenium WebDriver, where things get pretty easy:

```
// acquire text
if (acquire.equals("congratulations")) {
    sendMail("Something, tada badum tss!");
} else {
    driver.findElement(By.id("myButton")).click();
}
```

The mail sending part can be done in thousands of ways and depends on how you want to do it. The basic point where to start is the [JavaMail Webpage](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home). If you're uncomfortable with it, you may also look at the most common wrappers for it: [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) and [Jodd](http://jodd.org/doc/email.html).

Comment: Is it possible to make "some software" run selenium scripts according to a schedule ? That could free me of the need to make java code for my purpose. I don't even know how much time it will take to learn basic selenium java api and then make java code. Is it something that can be done in 2-3 hours ? The form is very simple. 6-7 simple fields only. All HTML, no JS and such.

Comment: I would use python to run the tests. Then call the python script from windows task manager or linux cron job. You can also call your java code from a task. If you can run it in command line then you can schedule it.